# Spa pump wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, 240v

The house we purchased has a 220/120 32 jet spa. The 220 drives a circulation pump, heater and runs the 2 hp 1-speed jet pump. The jet pump is poor quality and undersized for that amount of jets and the jet force Is really weak when all jets are opened. So I wanted to update the pump to a better flowing, higher HP.

I Ordered a high quality 48 frame 2.5hp 2-speed pump with dimensions that would fit. As I removed the old pump I saw that it was a 3-wire connection. Two hot and ground. There’s no neutral.

Not knowing this before, the pump I ordered has connections for 2 Hot, neutral and a ground. GCFI to the spa controller input is red hot, black hot, white neutral and ground. There is no neutral out from the spa controller.

So my question are 
1. Can I install the new pump and only connect two hot and ground 2. Do I  tap into the neutral coming from GCFI
3. Do I need to return this pump and find a 3-wire pump?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the pump's nameplate please?

Comment: Perhaps making "sleeves" to reduce slightly the diameter of each jet would have been a better, easier and cheaper option...

Answer (score 1):

Most hot tub/spas have a control board that it running everything. That control board, if not designed to run a 2 speed motor, will not have the necessary connections to do so. The GFCI likely feeds the control board, which feeds the motor, so the entire circuitry of the spa is protected by the GFCI. But all of this is "typical", we cannot know for sure, its something that must be seen in person.

Also, changing the HP of the motor changes the amount of current it uses, which may or may not be supported by the controller. This is something that should have only been endeavored after consulting with the OEM for the spa or one of their authorized service technicians.